# Absolute Two Column and Relative CSS Layout Madness - Content first

Tags: css

Goal:
A CSS two column layout with main content in the flow first followed by left nav (see example code). This is probably easier than I think but I could not find any clear cut example here or online. The left nav has to have a fixed width.

I would like to position the left nav and main content areas as you would expect (left nav then main content). This is for SEO purposes to place the content as high up in the flow as possible then position it appropriately. I need to have this work in IE6 as well. The main content area needs to expand with the browser window. With my current version the left nav is absolute positioned and overlaps the main content container. Thanks in advance for all you CSS gurus!!! Hopefully this can be of use to others as well.

```
<style>
.clearly {clear: both; font-size: 1px;}
.contentContainer {border:1px solid; width:800px;}
.leftNav {width:200px;background-color:#CCC;position:absolute;}
.mainContent { position:relative;left:200px;width:100%;float:left;background-color:#A6C9FF;}
</style>

<div class="contentContainer">    
<div class="mainContent">
Relative Main Content - Width 100%
</div>

<div class="leftNav">    
Absolute Left Nav<br />
Absolute Left Nav<br />
Absolute Left Nav<br />
</div>    
<div class="clearly"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are worrying about SEO - It doesn't NEED to work in IE6 - check out my blog in IE7 or below ;)

Comment: Thanks Myles a large percentage of my visitors are still IE6 (over 30%) so putting SEO aside I need it to appear correctly for them. Damn you IE6! lol

Comment: I know how you feel, but you can push them to change browser: http://browsesad.com/

Comment: The answers here work, I also welcome any other ideas now and in the future.I think there are several ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the containing div.

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding: 0; }
.mainContent
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.leftNav{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hFAaZ/

P.S. this has an advantage over the other answer in that any backgrounds applied to either nav or content areas will always fill the page. This is usually what is expected from the designer.

**Edit**

Just noticed that you need a fixed width on the container. Add .container to the `html,body` list above, then also add another rule to ste it's width to 100%;

Comment: Thanks so much Kevin. Is it possible to have this in a container div and or work with divs above and below it?

Comment: @chainwork. Treating the container like body/html per the css above should work just fine. Just make sure it has position relative in it. As for adding other blocks, you would need to tell whatever to leave room for those other blocks by altering the top/bottom/left/right declarations.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, could you have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong here. http://jsfiddle.net/hFAaZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/8uws6/

Simple semi-fluid + fixed layout:

Fluid column:

```
padding-left: 170px;
```

Fixed:

```
width:150px;
float:left;
background:red;
position:absolute;
```

Comment: Thanks Myles! Here is the issue I run into http://jsfiddle.net/8uws6/1/. There would be content that would go above and below it.

Comment: @chainwork you should really wrap the content in a tag of somesort, and if it is content it should be inside the content section unless it is a header or footer (coming from an SEO standpoint)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I realized in your example the content div follows the sidebar div. I need the content div above the sidebar div while maintaining the same appearance in the browser. Thanks for all your help, I owe you a beer.

Comment: Thank you Myles, please invoice me. Here is the dilema I face:
http://jsfiddle.net/8uws6/6/

Comment: That worked better, thank you Myles! Appreciate your time and your help.